# iOS: Add Interstitial Ad when performing a segue to a new viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, iad

I want to show an Interstitial Ad (from iAd framework) imediately after performing a segue between viewControllers in the storyboard.

I tried to launch `[interstitial presentInView:view]` (as stated in Apple Documentation) but the ad is not showing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve my doubt.

```
- (void) showFullScreenAd {
    if (requestingAd == NO) {
        interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        interstitial.delegate = self;
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
        [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
        requestingAd = YES;
    }
}

-(void) interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd{
    NSLog(@"interstitialAd DidLOAD");
    if (interstitialAd != nil && interstitial != nil && requestingAd == YES) {
        NSLog(@"interstitialDidPRESENT");
        [interstitial presentFromViewController:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: you're welcome! Depending on the internet connection the Ad requesting will take longer. I'll recommend you to load three InterStitial ads at the beginning of the session.